# How to Echo Metadata Value in Currency Format

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a Custom Post Type with a Metabox and an input Text field for adding "Price" to the posts. Now I would like to display the input value which can be like 49 or 59 like 49.00 or 59.00
so far I have this code to output the meta as:

```
$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '<h5> $'.$meta['price'][0].'/h5';
```

but this just return the value as $49 or $59. Can you please let know how I can make it to be render as `$49.00` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

$meta = get_post_custom($post->ID);
echo '<h5> $'.number_format($meta['price'][0], 2, '.', '').'/h5';
```